# How can I assign subroutine value to variable in access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have below procedure in `Module1`:

```
public sub Evaluate(Salary as double)
    Dim Overtimesalary as Double
    Overtimesalary = salary * 1.5
End Sub
```

Now, I am calling this procedure for my form click button event to calculate overtime salary and taking input value from textbox value from form, Code for that,

When I am trying to execute below code, I am getting "Compile error: Expected function or variable":

```
Private sub cmd_Calculate()
    Dim Test as Double
    test = Evaluate(txt.salary.value)
    MsgBox Test
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your subroutine into a Function, and return your value as the function's value.

```
public Function Evaluate(Salary as double)
    Evaluate = salary * 1.5
End Sub
```

This will run the procedure, perform the calculation, then return the value assigned within the function to the calling subroutine.

That said, I'm assuming that this is a simplified version of what you're actually doing - if all you're doing is literally multiplying a value by 1.5, you can just do that in the main subroutine!